# LINQ to SQL context.GetChanges

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in a LINQ to SQL dbml file. I am trying to get all the changes submitted to context, which I can get by using

```
var myOtherContext;
var changes = context.GetChangeSet();

foreach (var change in changes)
{         
    Type t = change.GetType();
    if (change is Product )
    {
        myOtherContext.GetTable<Product>().InsertOnSubmit((Product) change);
    }
    if (change is Supplier)
    {
        myOtherContext.GetTable<Supplier>().InsertOnSubmit((Supplier)change);
    }
}
```

Basically, I am copying all the changes that happened on one context to the other context (myOtherContext). I don't want to use an if statement to check the type of change. Is there any way I can write:

```
myOtherContext.GetTable<typeof(change)>().InsertOnSubmit((typeof(change) change);
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Parminder

Comment: Does Linq2SQL even allow to add entities from one context to be added to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the non-generic version:

```
foreach (var change in changes.Inserts) // note inserts
{         
    myOtherContext.GetTable(change.GetType()).InsertOnSubmit(change);
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a lot.